# Google image search in android

Tags: android, google-image-search

I need to implement Google image search in my app like [this example](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-google-image-search-api-example-json-parsing-web-api-call-demo/)

But the API using here is deprecated in [Google developer site](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide)

I need to implement the same like this sample. Is there any libraries available for google image search in android? Which is the recommended way to do this thing?

Answer (score -1):

Now, you can execute a search through HTTP query against https://serpapi.com/.

The service returns a nice JSON with all the images in the google search.
Also, SerpAPI provides the integration with Java. So, you find very easy to integrate this service in your application.

Images search documentation.
https://serpapi.com/images-results

Sample in Java.

```
Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<>();
parameter.put("q", "Coffee");
parameter.put("location", "Austin, Texas, United States");
parameter.put("hl", "en");
parameter.put("gl", "us");
parameter.put("google_domain", "google.com");
parameter.put("api_key", "yourkey");

GoogleSearchResults serp = new GoogleSearchResults(parameter);
JsonObject results = serp.getJson();
```

https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-java